# The theorem of the addition of velocities Employed in classical mechanics

Tags: reference-frames, velocity, relativity

The difference between the addition of velocities in Newtonian mechanics and relativity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classical mechanics the addition of velocities is based on Galilean transformations whereas in special relativity it’s based on the Lorentz transformations.

Hope this helps.